# Why is my code failing to copy one string to another?

Tags: c, string, pointers, visual-studio-2013

I want to write a C function called `append()` the target of which would be to append a character at the end of a given string. But, I am having trouble to get my code work because of some pointer-related issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void append(char ** string, int length, char ch)
{
    printf("%s", string);

    char * newString = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(length+2));

    strcpy(newString, string);

    newString[length ] = ch;
    newString[length + 1] = '\0';

    strcpy(string, newString);

    free(newString);
}

int main()
{
    char * string = "my1name234is56";
    append(string, strlen(string), 'x');

    printf("%s", string);
}
```

Inside the function `append()`: the second `strcpy()` before `free()` is giving me an exception, and the program is showing:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x5E8D40D9 (msvcr120d.dll) in mips_2_1.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00D1585C.
```

I have also tried

```
strcpy(*string, newString);
```

and

```
strcpy(**string, newString);
```

and, nothing seems to be working.

.

```
strcpy(&string, newString);
```

seems to be working, but, the end result is not what I would expect.

**Edit:** I made the edit according to **alk**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

void append(char ** string, int length, char ch)
{
    printf("%s\n\n", *string);

    char * newString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(length + 2));

    strcpy_s(newString, length+1, *string);

    newString[length] = ch;
    newString[length + 1] = '\0';

    strcpy_s(*string, length + 2, newString);

    *string = newString;
}

int main(void)
{
    char * string = "my1name234is56";
    append(&string, strlen(string), 'x');

    printf("%s", string);
}
```

its still not working.

**Edit2**: I made the following edit according to "**Weather Vane**":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

char * append(const char * string, int length, char ch)
{
    char * newString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(length + 5));

    printf("%s\n\n", string);

    strcpy_s(newString, length+5, string);

    newString[length] = ch;
    newString[length + 1] = '\0';

    return newString;
}

int main(void)
{
    char * string = "my1name234is56";

    printf("%s\n\n", string);

    char * string2 = append(string, strlen(string), 'x');

    printf("%s", string2);
}
```

Now, it is working.

Edit3: the following modification, according to **alk**, worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

void append(char ** string, int length, char ch)
{
    char * newString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(length + 2));

    strcpy_s(newString, length + 1, *string);

    newString[length] = ch;
    newString[length + 1] = '\0';

    *string = newString;
}

int main(void)
{
    char * string = "my1name234is56";

    printf("%s\n\n", string);

    append(&string, strlen(string), 'x');

    printf("%s\n\n", string);
}
```

Comment: Re the edit: the size of the allocated buffer is `length+2` but you tell `strcpy_s` that is it only has `length` available, but it needs `length+1` (for the terminator). Similar for the second `strcpy_s`, it needs `length+2`. The [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?view=vs-2017) says *The destination string must be large enough to hold the source string and its terminating null character*. And also says *if the destination string size `dest_size` is too small, the invalid parameter handler is invoked*

Comment: But did you try `strcpy_s(newString, length+1, *string);` ?

Comment: You did not `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: You didn't post the revised `main` either. Please post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When making all the recommended amendments (Alk's answer and my comments), it works.

Comment: When I copy/paste and compile your new code, it works.

Comment: I don't believe that.

Comment: what's wrong with `realloc`?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the function is passed a double pointer to a string literal.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes yes yes, that was a criticism at this ugly function

Comment: @WeatherVane, kindly, see the 2nd edit.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, kindly, see the 2nd edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.

Still, you need to change the value of the pointer you pass in to the value of the pointer to the memory you allocate instead of freeing it.

The below only shows the lines changed.

```
...

void append(char ** string, size_t length, char ch)
{
    printf("%s\n", *string);

    ...

    strcpy(newString, *string);

    ...

    *string = newString;
}

int main(void)
{
    ...
    append(&string, strlen(string), 'x');
    ...
}
```

You, BTW, do not need to pass in the size of the source, but you can easily derive it inside the function by doing `strlen(*string)`.

---

Sry for the incomplete code. I posted the answer from sitting behind a highly complete code-leakage-detection system, it seems.

Comment: Sorry, bro! I couldn't make your code work.

Comment: Drop this line `strcpy(string, newString);` from your code as well.

Comment: Have you seen the 1st **Edit** in my question? There is no such line.

Comment: When applying my adjustments to your original code just drop everything copying to `string`.

Comment: Drop the free statement as well.

Comment: Okay, give me a moment.

Comment: Also at least I did not recommend to use this unportable `strcpy_s()` thingy.

Comment: @alk I wonder who did - `strcpy_s()` wasn't used in the original code, nor in my answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane: most likely VS is to accuse... My irony was never pointing into to your direction.

Answer (score 2):

`char * string = "my1name234is56";` is a *string literal*. There are two reasons why you can't write the extended string back to it:

- There isn't enough memory for the extra character.
- It is read-only.

In any case, the function definition has too many stars, it should be

```
void append(char * string, int length, char ch)
```

Or even better

```
void append(const char * string, int length, char ch)
```

which indicates it should not be written to, and the whole idea is off-limits. You have to create a new string and return a pointer to that one

```
char *append(const char * string, int length, char ch) {
    // ...
    return newString;
}

int main() {
    //...
    string = append(string, strlen(string), 'x');
}
```